# STL vector.clear() cause memory double free or corruption is pthreads program

Tags: c++, stl, pthreads

Here is code snippet:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&hostsmap_mtx);
for (int i = 0; i < service_hosts[service].size(); ++i)
    poolmanager->delPool(service, service_hosts[service][i].first);

service_hosts[service].clear();
for (int i = 0; i < servers->count; ++i) {
    string temp(servers->data[i]);
    int pos = temp.find(':');
    string server = temp.substr(0, pos);
    string port = temp.substr(pos + 1, temp.length() - pos - 1);
    service_hosts[service].push_back(make_pair(server, atoi(port.c_str())));

    config.server = server;
    config.port = atoi(port.c_str());

    poolmanager->addPool(service, config);
}

pthread_mutex_unlock(&hostsmap_mtx);
```

The type of service_hosts is `map<string, vector<pair<string, int> > >`

Crash reason:
*** Error in './HttpProxy': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f6fe000a6b0 ***

And GDB bt:

```
5  ~basic_string (this=0x7f6fe0000960, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/basic_string.h:539  
6  ~pair (this=0x7f6fe0000960, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_pair.h:96  
7  _Destroy<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int> > (__pointer=0x7f6fe0000960)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_construct.h:93  
8  __destroy<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int>*> (__last=<optimized out>,
    __first=0x7f6fe0000960) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_construct.h:103  
9  _Destroy<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int>*> (__last=<optimized out>,
    __first=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_construct.h:126  
10 _Destroy<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int>*, std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int> > (
    __last=0x7f6fe0000970, __first=0x7f6fe0000960)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_construct.h:151  
11 _M_erase_at_end (this=<optimized out>, __pos=0x7f6fe0000960)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_vector.h:1352  
12 clear (this=0x7f6fe000a0f8) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_vector.h:1126
```

Any advice would be grateful.

Comment: my advice: make a [mcve]. If this alone wont help you to find the bug at least it will make it possible for others to help you

Comment: If you're using libcurl behind the scenes be wary that you need to take a few additional steps to make your code thread safe: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html . Check specially the "TLS" header, see if you're using OpenSSL and check if you have to implement the neccesary locks. In case this is what you need, please, do ask back if more info is needed.

Comment: @The Marlboro Man Only zookeeper is used,I'm trying find out the reason,but the cause is too strange,if I comment `service_hosts[service].clear();`, then it won't crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem may not be easy to find out the root cause.But finally I find out the reason.Cause stl `string` is not thread safe and stl `string` assignment is reference-count and COW. Eg:

```
string str = "stl::string";
string temp = str; //this is ref-count,COW
string temp2 = str.c_str(); //this is memory copy, cause string don't know how to handle const char *, just copy it
```

My fix is to pass `const char *` to stl vecotrs, and use `const char *` as function parameter in multithreading condition and if there is a contention. Eg:

```
map<string, vector<pair<string, int> > > Hostmap;
string service = "service";
string host = "host";
//Note: not service and host, but service.c_str() and host.c_str()
Hostmap[service.c_str()].push_back(make_pair(host.c_str(), 9966));
```

Hope this question will provide some hint to the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Double frees are very easy to diagnose using valgrind (or any other similar tool you have access to). It will tell you who freed the memory you are accessing which will lead you to the root of the problem. If you have problems reading the valgrind output post it here and we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice:)